# How to get Accurate Vive Controller Rotation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

How can I get HTC Vive Contollers vertical rotation around pivot angle?

Here is an example of what I'm going for: [the video of the motion](https://youtu.be/VhcB3J3jGq4), it has the angle I need to get.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, didn't see it until now.

You need to understand what is your base forward (Compare it to your starting forward or previous frame's forward) and your right direction (if you want a signed angle you need some reference because clockwise/anticlockwise depends on looking from up/down)

Here is a function that might help you:

```
public static class Extensions
{
public static float SignAngleCompareTo(this Transform that, Vector3 newForward, Vector3 refRight)
        {
            float angle = Vector3.Angle(newForward, that.forward);
            float sign = Mathf.Sign(Vector3.Dot(newForward, refRight));
            return sign * angle;

        }
}
```